# MVVM и коллекции

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть M, V, VM. Модель имеет ряд свойств. ВМ напрямую их транслирует.

```
public string Title
{
    get
    {
        return _model.Title;
    }
    set
    {
        _model.Title = value;
    }
}
```

Как то так. А в конструкторе ВМ прописано следующее

```
_model.Titlechanged += model_Titlechanged;
```

То есть если пользователь что то меняет на форме, то в сеттере ВМ меняется свойство модели, в сеттере модели срабатывает при этом событие, говорящее о том, что свойство изменилось. ВМ подхватывает это событие и в обработчике вызывает

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
```

**Теперь вопрос:**

Как сделать подобное для свойств с коллекциями, если коллекции модели содержат элементы типа `MyClassModel`, а коллекции ВМ - `MyClassViewModel`?

Для меня трудность вот в чем. В качестве коллекций в модели и ВМ я использую ObservableCollection. Но так как типы элементов в них разные, просто так транслировать я не могу. То есть во ВМ мне надо  менять тип содержимого коллекции, а значит следить непосредственно за ней и в случае возникновения `CollectionChanged` смотреть что где изменилось и повторять это действие в коллекции модели (что само по себе уже не удобно).

Ну а дальше происходит следующее. Коллекция модели принимает изменения (то есть изменяется сама), и, соответственно сигнализирует о том, что она изменилась. А на ее изменения подписана ВМ . Получается замкнутый круг. Можно, конечно, поэлементно сравнивать коллекции, чтобы выявить их эквивалентность, но это как то чересчур, мне кажется. Объясните, что я делаю не так!

Comment: А как вы отправляете изменения в модель из VM?

Comment: @VladD, ну там же в начале поста пример свойства в ВМ

Comment: Не вижу там передачу **в модель**, только подпись на свойство модели.

Comment: @VladD, эммм... `_model.Title = value;` не?

Comment: Окей. А как обстоит дело с коллекцией?

Comment: @VladD, да никак пока... все остановилось на этапе проектирования )

Comment: Окей, а почему бы не делать точно так же? Каждая `MyClassViewModel` следит за своей `MyClassModel`. Опишите, в чём именно сложность.

Comment: @VladD, в общих чертах я так себе это и представлял. Но в итоге получилось не такое уж простое и очевидное решение. Посмотрите мой ответ. интересно ваше мнение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что у меня в итоге получилось.

```
public class VmList<TModel, TViewModel> : IList<TViewModel>, IEnumerator<TViewModel>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged where TModel : ModelBase where TViewModel : ViewModelBase, new()
{
    IList<TModel> _list;
    IEnumerator<TModel> _enumerator;
    bool _modelListIsCollectionNotifier;

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public VmList(IList<TModel> list)
    {
        _list = list;

        {
            var notifier = _list as INotifyCollectionChanged;

            if (notifier != null)
            {
                _modelListIsCollectionNotifier = true;
                notifier.CollectionChanged += Notifier_CollectionChanged;
            }
        }

        {
            var notifier = _list as INotifyPropertyChanged;

            if (notifier != null)
                notifier.PropertyChanged += Notifier_PropertyChanged;
        }


        _enumerator = _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    private void Notifier_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    void Notifier_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    public TViewModel this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return new TViewModel { Model = _list[index] };
        }

        set
        {
            _list[index] = (TModel)value.Model;
            if(!_modelListIsCollectionNotifier)
                CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, index));
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _list.Count;
        }
    }

    public TViewModel Current
    {
        get
        {
            return new TViewModel { Model = _enumerator.Current };
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return _list.IsReadOnly;
        }
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public void Add(TViewModel item)
    {
        _list.Add((TModel)item.Model);
        if (!_modelListIsCollectionNotifier)
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
        if (!_modelListIsCollectionNotifier)
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    public bool Contains(TViewModel item)
    {
        return _list.Contains((TModel)item.Model);
    }

    public void CopyTo(TViewModel[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _enumerator.Dispose();
    }

    public IEnumerator<TViewModel> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public int IndexOf(TViewModel item)
    {
        return _list.IndexOf((TModel)item.Model);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, TViewModel item)
    {
        _list.Insert(index, (TModel)item.Model);
        if (!_modelListIsCollectionNotifier)
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index));
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return _enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    public bool Remove(TViewModel item)
    {
        var res = _list.Remove((TModel)item.Model);
        if (res && !_modelListIsCollectionNotifier)
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item));
        return res;
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _list.RemoveAt(index);
        if (!_modelListIsCollectionNotifier)
            CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, index));
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _enumerator.Reset();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Простите за отсутствие комментариев в коде. Происходит примерно следующее. Как видите, это универсальный класс зависимый от двух базовых типов: `ModelBase` и `ViewModelBase`. Целиком коллекция не дублируется из модели. Когда я запрашиваю элемент у `VmList'a`, класс берет соответствующий элемент из коллекции модели типа `ModelBase` и делает из него новый элемент типа `ViewModelBase`.

Вот листинг `ModelBase`. Не обращайте внимания, что он пуст, его задача состоит не в логике, а в присутствии. То есть это нужно, чтобы четко различать модель и вью модель. В дальнейшем я снабжу его сериализацией и чем нибудь еще, но для решения текущей задачи это не требуется.

```
[DataContract]
public class ModelBase: MvvmBase
{
}
```

А вот листинг `ViewModelBase`.

```
public class ViewModelBase: MvvmBase
{
    bool _initialized;
    ModelBase _model;
    Lookup<string, string> _relatives;

    public ViewModelBase() { }

    public ViewModelBase(ModelBase model)
    {
        Model = model;
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        DependentAttribute attr;
        var tmpRel = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this))
        {
            attr = (DependentAttribute)pd.Attributes[typeof(DependentAttribute)];
            if (attr != null)
                tmpRel.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(attr.PropertyName, pd.Name));
            else
            {
                var modelProp = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Model)[pd.Name];
                if (modelProp != null)
                    tmpRel.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(modelProp.Name, pd.Name));
            }
        }
        _relatives = (Lookup<string, string>)tmpRel.ToLookup(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);

        Model.PropertyChanged += Model_PropertyChanged;
        Initialized = Model != null;
    }

    protected virtual void Model_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var propName in _relatives[e.PropertyName])
            OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    internal protected ModelBase Model
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }
        set
        {
            _model = value;
            Initialize();
        }
    }

    public bool Initialized
    {
        get
        {
            return _initialized;
        }

        set
        {
            _initialized = value;
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModelBase<TModel> : ViewModelBase where TModel: ModelBase
{
    public ViewModelBase() { }
    public ViewModelBase(TModel model) : base(model) { }

    protected internal new TModel Model
    {
        get
        {
            return (TModel)base.Model;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Model = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Как видите тут 2 класса. Общий и типизированный. Тут еще встречается тип `DependentAttribute`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class DependentAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public DependentAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

Происходит примерно следующее. Когда у модели срабатывает событие `PropertyChanged`, вью модель смотрит, есть ли у нее такое же свойство, и если есть, вызывает уже у себя событие `PropertyChanged`. Так вот, если в модели у вас свойство называется `CircRad`, а во вью модели вы хотите назвать его `Radius`, то вы просто вешаете на свойство `Radius` атрибут `[Dependent("CircRad")]` и при изменении в модели свойства `CircRad`, ВМ будет сообщать об изменении свойства `Radius`. то есть в идеале свойство в ВМ будет выглядеть так

```
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Вместо

```
public string SomeProperty
{
    get
    {
        return _model.SomeProperty;
    }
    set
    {
        _model.SomeProperty = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeProperty));
    }
}
```

Конечно, если вам нужно предусмотреть логику взаимодействия, то свойство придется раскрыть. Хотя я просто внутри ВМ подписываюсь на собственное `PropertyChanged` и в зависимости от имени свойства, которое поменялось, выполняю те или иные действия. Не знаю, насколько это правильно, но мне так проще.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, для чего у вас список реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`. `_list` скорее всего не будет реализовывать `INotifyPropertyChanged` самостоятельно. А в остальном, да, вроде бы правильная имплементация.

Comment: @VladD, на самом деле у различных коллекций есть свойства, не обозначенные в интерфейсах (количество элементов, максимальное количество, заморозка и др). Я не стал изучать все доступные коллекции (тем более коллекции могут быть и пользовательскими) на реализацию оповещений, а просто сразу это предусмотрел. Кстати, предусмотрел не до конца. По идее нужно еще наследоваться от класса `TypeDescriptor`, который бы ловил обращение к "несуществующим" свойствам из XAML'a и позволял их обрабатывать

Comment: Мне кажется, не нужно предоставлять все интерфейсы. Достаточно `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Даже `INotifyPropertyChanged` мне кажется излишним (если это не для WinForms).

Comment: @VladD, вероятнее всего вы правы, в 99,9% случаев это не понадобится, в остальных случаях задачу можно решить иначе. Но я все же оставлю это.

Answer (score 0):

1. Зачем такие сложности со связыванием VM и M и объявлением свойств-врапперов? Не проще ли во VM объявить свойство Model, а M сделать с INPC-свойствами (чтобы она сама кидала PropertyChanged)? В XAML, соответственно, будут биндинги в стиле {Binding Model.Title}.
2. Если со свойствами-коллекциями сделать так же, как написал выше, то коллекция будет только одна - в M. Я не совсем понял, надо ли еще следить за изменениями свойств элементов в этой коллекции. Если да, то придется дописывать код для слежения за существующими и добавленными/удаленными элементами в ObservableCollection.

В целом, лучше использовать какой-нибудь из известных MVVM-фреймворков, которые упростят все эти вещи. Лично я использую ReactiveUI, но это не самый простой вариант для новичков.

Comment: Сложность в том, что у модели может быть другая thread affinity: она может бежать в фоновом потоке (и обычно так и делает). Поэтому для того, чтобы к ней можно было получить доступ, нужна как минимум синхронизация.

Comment: Есть и другие причины так не делать. А вообще я уже описал класс VmList и если надо, позже выложу на всеобщее обозрение. Если кратко, то класс этот не создает новую коллекцию на основе коллекции из модели, а транслирует элементы коллекции модели, создавай лишь нужный элемент вью модели из запрошенного элемента коллекции (ну и конечно следит за изменениями, если модель о них сообщает и направляет их уже от своего имени). Само собой базовый класс вью модели имеет возможность создаваться на основе модели и VmList об этом знает )

Comment: ок, забыл про синхронизацию ) для случаев с коллекциями у себя я использую расширение из ReactiveUI: modelCollection.CreateDerivedCollection(m => new MyClassViewModel(m))

Comment: Ну я не всегда вижу смысл в создании `class ModelCollection : IList<Model>`. Чаще всего проще обойтись обычным `List<Model>` или `ObservableCollection<Model>`. Да и негоже модели заниматься созданием ВМ )

Comment: Вы не так поняли - derived-коллекция создается во ВМ и доступна для биндинга через свойство этой ВМ. Естественно модель ничего не должна знать про ВМ. Просто я использую готовое решение, а вы решили написать сами :)